# .net: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file

Tags: .net, vb.net, compilation, clickonce, code-signing

Using VB.net 2013. When compiling my project, I am able to get it compile a few times but after a few compilations it stops compiling and systematically throws the error:

```
Error   1   "The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly." "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file" '[...]\bin\Debug\app.publish\KSDoc.exe' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.PathUtil.IsPEFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFileInternal(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String signingTargetPath, Boolean certIsSha256, Boolean targetFrameworkSupportsSha256)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(String certThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String signingTargetPath, String targetFrameworkVersion)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() KSDoc
```

If I untick the option "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" under the Signing tab, the application compiles, but this is not a viable alternative. I need to sign the application.

The certificate is also installed and valid (i.e. it is not expired).

If I reboot the PC the issue seems to go away for a while but then comes back again.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging into the problem, I ran Process Monitor (from Sysinternals), and found that the EXE file being compiled (in my case KSDoc.exe) was being accessed by both the Visual Studio IDE and by a 3rd party process called **PSANHost.exe**

Turns out PSANHost.exe belongs to the Panda Antivirus (Panda Cloud Antivirus). **After uninstalling Panda the problem went away.**

It is important to notice Panda was not flagging the executable with any kind of risk; apparently it was just holding a lock on the file at the wrong time.
It also worth mentioning that *"Disabling" the AV does not fix the problem. You must actually Uninstall it from your PC.*

So far everything has been working great. (went back to MS Security Essentials)

Comment: Wow, I am so glad you posted this answer! I had no idea what was wrong but turning off Panda Antivirus worked for me. No need for uninstall anymore it seems

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I worked hard to find it until this morning where I saw this post... It's Panda also who lock the files, I had the same problem with Avast before.

Comment: good to know I'm not alone here! I must still emphasize that MS Security Essentials doesn't cause this problem so this is what I'm using now (on a Win7 x64 machine). How about you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Panda is the cause.
However if you enter folder in which you store your project files in the Panda's Exception list it will not make you problems any more.

Comment: from my experience, at the time I made the original post,I don't recall if I added the folder to the exception list; I do recall turning off Real Time scanning did not resolve the issue though (which was confusing while troubleshooting: it turned out Panda still locked the files; just didn't scan them). I believe some things may have changed in Panda since then though; anyway just though this was worth pointing out.